# Tokenize mixed content in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I have an element `<mixed>` that contains mixed content. Is it possible to use XSLT (2.0) to wrap all “words” (delimited by the pattern `\s+`, for example) inside `<mixed>` in a `<w>` tag, descending into inline elements when necessary? For example, given the following input:

```
<mixed>
  One morning, when <a>Gregor Samsa</a>
  woke from troubled dreams, he found
  himself transformed in his bed into
  a <b><c>horrible vermin</c></b>.
</mixed>
```

I want something like the following output:

```
<mixed>
  <w>One</w> <w>morning,</w> <w>when</w> <a><w>Gregor</w> <w>Samsa</w></a>
  <w>woke</w> <w>from</w> <w>troubled</w> <w>dreams,</w> <w>he</w> <w>found</w>
  <w>himself</w> <w>transformed</w> <w>in</w> <w>his</w> <w>bed</w> <w>into</w>
  <w>a</w> <b><c><w>horrible</w></c></b> <w><b><c>vermin</c></b>.</w>
</mixed>
```

Dimitre Novatchev provided a template in an answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484569/wrapping-words-from-html-using-xsl) that goes much of the way to solving this, but does not satisfy the following requirements:

- Inline elements that terminate within a “word” should be split so that a single `<w>` element contains the whole “word.” Otherwise there would be invalid XML, such as:

  ```
    <w>a</w> <w><b><c>horrible</w> <w>vermin</c></b>.</w>
  ```

  However, this template detaches the punctuation `.` after `vermin` and produces:

  ```
    <w>a</w> <b><c><w>horrible</w> <w>vermin</w></c></b> <w>.</(w>
  ```

  (Edit: None of the current 3 answers satisfy this requirement.)
- The split token must not be discarded. Consider the  similar task of wrapping non-coefficient numbers in `<sub>` tags in the context of a chemical formula. For example, `<reactants>2H2 + O2</reactants>` becomes `<reactants>2H<sub>2</sub> + O<sub>2</sub></reactants>`. This is not possible using the `tokenize` function because it simply discards the separator. Instead we will probably have to fall back on `analyze-string`.

If not XSLT, what is the best method to do this?

Comment: Hi Michael, none of the posted answers have solved my question. What do I do then? I don't really have enough rep for bounties.

Comment: IMHO, you need to better define the problem. No one can provide an algorithm to solve a problem if they don't know how to solve it manually using only paper and pencil - and a few clear rules.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, this would provide the expected result in your example:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::mixed]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <w>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </w>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I did not understand your point regarding "*Inline elements that terminate within a “word”*". What would be the expected result when, for example, a part of a word is italicized?

Comment: I consider `vermin.` to be a single word because it doesn’t contain the separator pattern `\s+`. However the inline elements `<b>` and `<c>` are opened in a previous word but are closed in the middle of that word: `vermin</c></b>.` So in order to wrap only `vermin.` in one element, it must be that the inline elements `<b>` and `<c>`, that are part of several words, are split. An example of the expected result is already in my post: `<w>a</w> <b><c><w>horrible</w></c></b> <w><b><c>vermin</c></b>.</w>`. Please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the suggested solution does what you want in that regard - although for an entirely different reason, namely that each text node is processed individually.

Comment: I believe that your solution wraps spaces, not words, with `<w>` because the `regex` parameter in `analyze-string` is `\s+`. Even when changed to `\S+`, the output ends with `<w>vermin</w></c></b><w>.</w>`.

Comment: "*I believe that your solution wraps spaces, not words*" Right, fixed now. -- "*the output ends with...*" We need clearer rules here. Until then, if a period is a part of a word, then a single period is a one-letter word. If you want each text node to also consider the previous/next nodes, this will get **much** more complicated.

Comment: Indeed, it's a complicated problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `analyze-string` on `\S+` with

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mixed//text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\S+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <w>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </w>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

you get

```
<mixed>
  <w>One</w> <w>morning,</w> <w>when</w> <a><w>Gregor</w> <w>Samsa</w></a>
  <w>woke</w> <w>from</w> <w>troubled</w> <w>dreams,</w> <w>he</w> <w>found</w>
  <w>himself</w> <w>transformed</w> <w>in</w> <w>his</w> <w>bed</w> <w>into</w>
  <w>a</w> <b><c><w>horrible</w> <w>vermin</w></c></b><w>.</w>
</mixed>
```

Do you really want to join the trailing dot with the preceding `vermin` that is inside of your inline elements?

Comment: Correct, I do want to join the trailing dot.

Answer (score 0):

How about this XSLT, which has an extra template to cope with elements that are immediately followed by a text node containing only a full stop.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '[\s]')[.]">
   <w><xsl:sequence select="."/></w>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space() = '.']" />

 <xsl:template match="node()[following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][normalize-space() = '.']]">
  <w>
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
     <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  </w>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```